# Mapping records with AutoMapper's ProjectTo() throws exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, automapper

Here is a gist for reproducing the bug: https://gist.github.com/CollinAlpert/075d341fc0e24bb8f4eb8053983d93df

I have am trying to map EF Core queries to records using AutoMapper's `ProjectTo` method.
Mapping using the `mapper.Map()` method works fine, so my mapping doesn't seem to be the problem. However when calling `ProjectTo`, the following exception gets thrown.

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Unable to create a map expression from Station.IsActive (System.Int32) to Boolean.IsActive (System.Boolean)

Mapping types:
Station -> StationDto
Test.Station -> Test.StationDto

Type Map configuration:
Station -> StationDto
Test.Station -> Test.StationDto

Destination Member:
IsActive

   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Test.Program.Main() in /Users/collin/Programmieren/dotNET/Test/Test/Program.cs:line 24
```

Comment: A PR is welcome. The `MapFrom` should override the mapping by convention. You can also rename the source or destination property.

Comment: A similar issue is noted in [this discussion](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3628) - perhaps try adding a `ForMember` mapping as well? I suspect EF would use the private setter rather than the constructor. If that doesn't work (or maybe if it does too!) you're probably best logging an issue there.

Comment: A better idea is to replace the resolver with a map from `int` to `bool`.

Comment: did you try rewriting it with a ternair operator? (is.IsActive == 1) ? true : false. This almost certainly will not make a difference, but who knows.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Adding a resolver from `int` to `bool` solved this issue, thanks. I used `mapperConfig.CreateMap<int, bool>().ConvertUsing(i => i == 1);`

Comment: That's called a type converter or a map :) `MapFrom` is a resolver, it's the source of the mapping.